# Failed to execute script app in python pls help me

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, keylogger

Recently I've made a python app and when I change it to a `exe` file it is saying **Failed to execute script app**

When I run it in console it is showing like this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
  packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site- 
  packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
 ImportError
 [104] Failed to execute script app
```

Answer (score 1):

So, What I did is I added an extra parameter --debug in the pyinstaller command and removing the --windowed parameter so that I can see what is actually happening when the app is clicked and I found out there was an error that made a lot of sense when I trace it, it basically complained that "some_image.jpg" no such file or directory.

The reason why it complains and didn't complain when I ran the script from the first place or even using the command line "./" is because the file image existed in the same path as the script located but when pyinstaller created "dist" directory which has the app product it makes a perfect sense that the image file is not there and so I basically moved it to that dist directory where the clickable app is there!

Comment: But the error is not that thw problem is in pynput library ???????